# Maquette JS Conditional CSS

Tags: maquette

I am trying to create an array of 'li' elements that hold icons for app level navigation.  I have a css class "is-active" that highlights the active 'li' element in the list indicating the active location in the nav schema.  I expect Maquette JS to render the appropriate icon as 'highlighted' when it is selected by the end user.  I am trying to use the classes:{} property as such:

```
"classes": this._activeNavElementId === navItem.id ? "nav-menu-item nav-menu-item-is-active" : "nav-menu-item", ...
```

Clearly this is an improper use.  The tutorial provides an example where the boolean determines if a class is in the classList; however, I actually need to use classList A if true or classList B if false.

Having a hard time finding good examples of maquettejs conditional css.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I am using the following code to try and create the conditional hyperscript where the variable `classValue` is a boolean.  
`return h("li.nav-menu-item", {
            "key": navItem.id,
            classes: {classValue: "nav-menu-item-is-active"}
          }) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional CSS classes work as follows:

```
h("li.nav-menu-item", {
  "classes": {
    "nav-menu-item-is-active": this._activeNavElementId === navItem.id
  }
}
```